# Do any of the manga from Bakuman exist in real life?

Tags: bakuman

Do any of the manga from *Bakuman* exist in real life? Are there any plans to make some of them? I would especially love to read [*Classroom of Truth*](http://bakuman.wikia.com/wiki/Classroom_of_Truth).

Answer (score 8):

There are two direct official adaptations of Bakuman's manga in real life.

---

## [Otter 11](http://myanimelist.net/manga/21274/Rakko_11-gou)

As @ʞɹɐzǝɹ said, Otter 11 has been published in Shonen Jump as a oneshot by [Takeshi Obata](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takeshi_Obata)(Art) and [Tsugumi Oba](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsugumi_%C5%8Cba)(Story), which are the same persons that made Bakuman.

[image: Otter11]

---

## [PCP (Perfect Crime Party)](http://myanimelist.net/manga/92906/PCP:_Kotou_no_Kodomotachi)

PCP has been adapted as a novel by [Takeshi Obata](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takeshi_Obata)(Art) which is the illustrator of Bakuman, and [Sei Hatsuno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sei_Hatsuno)(Story).

[image: PCP]